# Xamarin - Delete item from CollectionView, Command does not get called

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, mobile

I'm very new to Xamarin and i've built a simple app where you can add strings to an ObservableCollection and render it via a CollectionView Element.
Now i've also made a delete Button next to each of these strings in the collection to delete one entry. Therefore i want to call my 'DeleteCommand'.
But when i'm debugging the application i can see that the DeleteCommand in the Constructor doesn't get called when clicking on the delete Button. The command should get the string of the entry as parameter.

Here my XAML-Code:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestProjectXamarin"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="TestProjectXamarin.MainPage">


    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:MainPageViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height=".5*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image Source="" BackgroundColor="PowderBlue"
               Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Editor Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Placeholder="Enter Note Here"
                Margin="10,10" Text="{Binding TheNote}"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" BackgroundColor="LimeGreen"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="Erase" Command="{Binding EraseCommand}" BackgroundColor="OrangeRed"/>

        <CollectionView x:Name="collectionView" ItemsSource="{Binding AllNotes}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Frame Margin="5">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height=".5*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Label Text="{Binding .}" Grid.Row="0"/>
                                <Button Text="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

And also my CS-Code:

```
    namespace TestProjectXamarin
{
    public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
            EraseCommand = new Command(() =>
            {
                TheNote = string.Empty;
            });

            SaveCommand = new Command(() =>
            {
                AllNotes.Add(TheNote);

                TheNote = string.Empty;
            });

            DeleteCommand = new Command<string>(
                execute: (string arg) =>
                {
                    TheNote = arg;
                }
            );
        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> AllNotes { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        string theNote;

        public string TheNote
        {
            get => theNote;
            set
            {
                theNote = value;
                var args = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(TheNote));

                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, args);
            }
        }

        public Command SaveCommand { get; }
        public Command EraseCommand { get; }
        public Command DeleteCommand { private set; get; }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Can't i call a command out of such a CollectionView this way? Or is there a more propriet way for deleting an item?

Would be thankful if someone can help me on this!

Comment: the binding context of each element in your CollectionView is just a string (because your ItemsSource is an IEnumerable<String>) and a string does not have a DeleteCommand property.  You either need to update your binding paths to point to your base VM, or just use the Button's Clicked event, which is not dependent on the binding context

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DeleteCommand` is in your ViewModel so the solution is:

1.Define a name of your page, let's call it `MyPage`:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App283"
             mc:Ignorable="d"

             x:Name="MyPage"

             x:Class="App283.MainPage">
```

2.Then bind your `DeleteCommand` like this:

```
<Button Text="Delete" Command="{Binding BindingContext.DeleteCommand, Source={x:Reference MyPage}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Grid.Row="1"/>
```